# Characters count only start counting on the 2nd character?

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard-events

I have a function that calculates how many characters remaining the user can type, but I don't know why it only starts counting from the 2nd characters. Means at the end I will able to type an extra character from the maximum amount I set.

```
wInput.maxChars=30

wInput.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, calculate);
private function calculate(event:Event=null):void {
                NameRC=wInput.maxChars-wInput.length;
                remainingA.text=NameRC;

        }
```

wInput function:

```
private function input():void {
            //name input
            wInputF.font=arial.fontName;
            wInputF.color=0x818181;
            wInputF.size=15;
            wInputF.align=TextFormatAlign.JUSTIFY;
            wInputF.leftMargin=5;
            wInputF.rightMargin=10;


            wInput.defaultTextFormat=wInputF;
            wInput.border=true;
            wInput.borderColor=0xE6E6E6;
            wInput.selectable=true;
            wInput.type=TextFieldType.INPUT;
            wInput.maxChars=30;
            wInput.width=wBox.width-wType.textWidth-70;
            wInput.height=wInput.textHeight+5;
            wInput.x=wBox.x+wType.width+10;
            wInput.y=wType.y-5;
            wBox.addChild(wInput);

            //calculate remaining characters
            remaining();
            remainingC.x=wInput.x+wInput.width+20;
            remainingC.y=wInput.y+12;
            wInput.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, calculate);
        }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that wInput is in fact a normal TextInput component? If that's the case, I'm not seeing why this wouldn't work.

Comment: its not a component, its a dynamic created text-field.
it could count, but only from the 2nd characters...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what nameRC is, and if wInput is the TextField, where do you set its .text property? Anyway, going on the only place that you set a .text property, which is:

```
remainingA.text=NameRC;
```

I'd guess that it could be doing it always 1 digit behind because you do the max - length calculation before you add anything to the TextField. So like, when you first do that calculation, there's nothing in the TextField, *even though* you just caught a Keyboard event.  So it'll return 0; then after that you add something to the field. So the next time that Keyboard event is fired, it's one behind. My only guess is that you just need to swap those lines around.

I could be *way* off, though ;)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this from a random google search and I figured it out from debu's comment about how the textfield didn't have the character in it yet when the event fired off. Light bulb! Seemed so obvious after that, I changed KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN to KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP. Seems to work how I want it to now. Hope this helps almost 2 years later!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
wInput.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, calculate);
private function calculate(event:Event=null):void 
{
remainingA.text=String(wInput.text.length);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code, change from `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, calculate` to `KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, calculate`

Comment: This answer has already been given by vanhomRF more than one year ago!